# Handle Interrupt from a thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code for creating multiple threads.

```
    AtomicBoolean shutdown = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!shutdown.get()) {
                try {
                    factory.get().run();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Exception occurred in the thread execution ", e);
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        threadList.add(thread);
    }
```

Now, what I wanted to do is that when any interruption occurs, I want to change the value of shutdown variable to true so that it would kill all the threads. How can I add such a handler in this code?

Comment: What do you mean by "any interruption occurs"?

Comment: Have you considered using an [ExecutorService](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial) instead of writing your own thread pool?

Answer (score 0):

Does something like below works for you ( interrupt() call is not necessary, added for flow visibility).  I would also recommend looking into java ExecutorService implementation instead of spawning the threads.

```
AtomicBoolean shutdown = new AtomicBoolean(false);
for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("sleep for 5s");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Thread8")){
                    throw new InterruptedException();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" interrupted. Setting shutdown to true");
                shutdown.set(true);
            }

            if(shutdown.get()){
                System.out.println("Found shutdown instruction..exiting loop for "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        } while (!shutdown.get());
    });
    thread.start();
    thread.setName("Thread"+i);
}
```